# Making a module with classes accessible as a direct child of the imported module

Tags: python, python-3.5

So I'm making a module that will be have classes that will be accessible globally, and I am having an issue with how they are called.

Let's call my module `jacks_lib`. In it, there is a file called `website_export` with a class named `ExportFromWebsite`

The following code works fine, but it's sloppy and I don't like it:

```
import jacks_lib.website_export
export = jacks_lib.website_export.ExportFromWebsite()
```

This is how I want my code to work:

```
import jacks_lib
export = jacks_lib.ExportFromWebsite()
```

Is this possible to do? Or at least make `import jacks_lib` automatically import `website_export.py` too?

Comment: "Let's call my module `jacks_lib`. In it, there is a file called `website_export`" - wait, what? Is `jacks_lib` a package? Is `website_export` a file name or a module name? If it's a file name, why doesn't it end in `.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module, you have an `__init__.py` file.

In it, you can put something like

```
from website_export import ExportFromWebsite
```

This should let you do what you want

Comment: Thanks! I kept doing `__all__ = ['website_export']` and getting confused on why it didn't work.

Comment: OK, so I did this on a subfolder called *creds*. It's a subfolder of *website_import*. When I run the \_\_init\_\_.py in *creds* folder, which contains `from credentials import login`, there is no error. But when I try to have a python file in *website_import* run `import creds` I get the error "ImportError: No module named 'credentials'"

Comment: OK I figured it out. I have to add a period before `credentials` so that parent folders can use it. Kinda weird....

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out after toying around:

In the file `__init__.py` you have to put in `from file_name import ClassName`

In my case, I would make `__init__.py` contain:

```
from website_import import ExportFromWebsite
```